# Is there a programmatic way to change user agent in Cypress.io?

Tags: browser, e2e-testing, cypress

I have some ad calls that are only made on mobile devices.  In Chrome, I can use Device Mode and simulate a mobile device, and the resulting ad call from the server is correctly tailored to mobile.  I'm not sure how Chrome does this, except possibly by sending a different user agent.

In the Cypress.io documentation, it says the user agent can be changed in the configuration file (Cypress.json).  But, I need to run a test for a desktop viewport and then a mobile viewport with a mobile user agent.  Is there a way to change the user agent programmatically?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update**: According to https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3873 it is possible since Cypress 3.3.0 use `user-agent` property in a `cy.request()` and `cy.visit()`.

If you need, for example, set `userAgent` as **Googlebot**:

```js
cy.visit(url, {
    headers: {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)',
    }
});
```

---

#### Original answer before Cypress 3.3.0

```js
before(() => {
    cy.visit(url, {
        onBeforeLoad: win => {
            Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, 'userAgent', {
                value: 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)',
            });
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have luck with the newer answer (even on 3.3.0+). But the old stub worked.

Comment: userAgent is ignored at runtime, neither of solutions worked
https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config#Notes

Comment: This is working in my local, but it is not working on staging. on the staging, i am getting fixed user agent  each time which is `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux aarch64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cypress/12.1.0 Chrome/106.0.5249.51 Electron/21.0.0 Safari/537.36`

Comment: The second option is not for me as i am using cy.request

Answer (score 5):

**Update as of Aug 12, 2021:**

It seems you can't change the user agent anymore: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config#Notes

---

Old answer:

Now cypress supports passing user agent in the header for cy.visit as well as cy.request:

```
it('Verify Social Sharing Meta Tags', () => {
  cy.visit(portalURL + '/whats_new/140', {
    headers: {
      'user-agent': 'LinkedInBot/1.0 (compatible; Mozilla/5.0; Apache-HttpClient +http://www.linkedin.com)',
    }
  });

  cy.document().get('head meta[name="og:type"]')
    .should('have.attr', 'content', 'website');
});
```

https://on.cypress.io/changelog#3-3-0

Comment: Seems you can't change the userAgent at runtime 
https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config#Notes

Comment: Updated the response.

Comment: Thanks for note, user agent changed in config file instead of runtime code

Answer (score 2):

The other answers do not set the `User-Agent` header of the underlying HTTP request, just the `userAgent` property of `win.navigator`. To set the `User-Agent` header to a custom value for all HTTP requests, you can set the [`userAgent` configuration option](https://on.cypress.io/configuration#Browser):

```
{
  // rest of your cypress.json...
  "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the programmatic part doesn't work: see https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config.html#Not-all-config-values-can-be-changed-at-all-times

Comment: `userAgent` is special and cannot be changed at run time with `Cypress.config()`: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config#Not-all-config-values-can-be-changed-at-all-times