# How to set user-agent in cypress Version 6

Tags: cypress

What is te correct way to set the user-agent in cypress Version 6 and later? Everthing i testet is not working. The Header Information is not send.
Is there is a workaround?
Is it possible to set the user-agent dynamically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a programmatic way to change user agent in Cypress.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048880/is-there-a-programmatic-way-to-change-user-agent-in-cypress-io)

Answer (score 2):

You can override your user-agent by providing its value in `cypress.json` file, something like:

```
{
  "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
}
```

You can get the list of Commonly used User agents from the [User-Agent MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent).