# How to set different UserAgents in Cypress programmatically

Tags: mobile, browser, cypress, ui-automation, user-agent

I have a use case of running cypress tests in different mobile/tablet browsers. I did read about setting userAgent in cypress through Configuration file: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Options, but this will be set in configuration file.

I am looking for ways to set UserAgent through CLI or run time...meaning I want to run the same test for different userAgents. Did anyone work on this use case? How do we set userAgent in this case?

Thanks,
Saahith

Answer (score 1):

You can override an existing configuration value in the `cypress.json` file using `cypress_`. You can look here in the [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Overriding-Configuration)

For example, if you already have a *userAgent* set in your `cypress.json` file but for your test execution you need a different *userAgent*, you execute the command:

```
cypress_userAgent="value" npx cypress run
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Overriding Options - Command Line](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Command-Line)

> When running Cypress from the Command Line you can pass a --config flag

For **command line usage**

```js
cypress open --config userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"
```

For **package.json** usage (note escaped double quotes in the string)

```js
"scripts: {
  ...
  "cy:ua-moz": "cypress open --config userAgent=\"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0\""
```

Check it in the Cypress runner under Settings/Configuration - it is flagged with the "***set from CLI arguments***" color.

---

Or programatically within the test, [Cypress.config()](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Cypress-config)

and [Is there a programmatic way to change user agent in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55382483/8745435)

```js
const userAgents = {
  "Firefox": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0",
  "Opera": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36 OPR/38.0.2220.41",
  "Safari": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
}

userAgents.forEach(ua => {

  Cypress.config('userAgent', userAgents[ua]); // set outside of test
                                               // see caveat below

  it(`Test with user agent ${ua}`, () => {
    // test here
  }
}
```

**ALTHOUGH** some indication of trouble with this method
[Not all config values can be changed at all times](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config.html#Notes)

> Some configuration values cannot be changed while running a test. Anything that’s not directly under Cypress’s control - like timeouts, userAgent, or environment variables - will be ignored at run-time.

Comment: Note: I noticed that long userAgent strings would throw an error in Cypress!
`npx cypress open --config userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A356 Safari/604.1"` gives this error:

Cypress encountered an error while parsing the argument: --config

You passed: userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A356 Safari/604.1

Making it much smaller fixed it!