# Cypress - best way to test multiple user agent strings

Tags: cypress

This is a continuation of [Is there a programmatic way to change user agent in Cypress.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048880/is-there-a-programmatic-way-to-change-user-agent-in-cypress-io). I am making a simple page that directs a user to the appropriate application store to download the native app. I rely on the user agent string to identify Android/iOS/other and then present the corresponding text/button/link.

Based on the question linked above, it appears as thought the only way to accomplish this to run Cypress multiple times: `npx cypress run --config userAgent=[userAgent string]` for each `userAgent string`. Is this correct? Or is there a way to do it without creating a new script?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it seems that is the solution.

For example:

```
$ cypress run --config userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0"
```

The problem with setting user agent at runtime is that Cypress ignores it and a default value is sent to the server. You can find out in DevTools after the test finishes running.

Cypress mentions in the docs that it can be done with setting `userAgent` config value, one mention of that is on `cy.visit()` doc page: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#User-agent